# Impossible to install PHP 7.1 on Debian Stretch

Tags: php, debian, libc, debian-stretch

I'm trying to install PHP 7.1 on Debian stretch and i get this error:

```
root@67a59862eeed:/var/www# apt install php7.1-apcu php7.1-bcmath php7.1-cli php7.1-curl php7.1-fpm php7.1-gd php7.1-intl php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql php7.1-soap php7.1-xml php7.1-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php-apcu' instead of 'php7.1-apcu'
php7.1-gd is already the newest version (7.1.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
php7.1-mysql is already the newest version (7.1.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
php7.1-xml is already the newest version (7.1.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.1-cli : Depends: php7.1-opcache but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
 php7.1-curl : Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable
 php7.1-fpm : Depends: php7.1-opcache but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
 php7.1-intl : Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
 php7.1-zip : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
```

Here is what i'm doing:

```
$ apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
$ wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
$ sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
$ apt update
```

It seems that my current version of libc6 is the latest version (2.24-11). I don't know how to resolve that.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: "php7.1" is not an official package in stretch. where are you installing it from?

Comment: have a look on https://angristan.fr/installer-php-7-debian-8-jessie-depot-dotdeb/

Comment: You have a mixed sources.list Stretch + Buster , please add `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to the question.